# Update a table with values from a temp table (imported from excel)

Tags: sql, ms-access, sql-update

all.
I have a table where I need to update information in rows with the most up-to-date information from an excel spreadsheet.

I figured i would need the information inside of ACCESS first, so I imported and normalized the table and a few other things.

Now, the old table would have a row with a blank space in say column 3 where as the same row from the spreadsheet now has information in column 3. I need to update 14 columns with the newest information from the spreadsheet.

I'm not sure what else I need to tell you, thanks for any help and let me know if you need additional information.

Comment: The two tables share a PK.

Comment: Will you drive this process from within an Access session or an Excel session?